# How to track network changes periodically

Tags: java, android, performance, broadcastreceiver, ping

I have a piece of code taken from this answer to track the server IP ping result changes in the app.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/28856469/6173138
The problem with this code is that it was only able to track the ping changes on the first run.. and I want to track it periodically. I want it to work like detecting the Internet Connection using BroadcastReceiver but in my case would be detecting ping status.

Can anyone help me on this please? Really appreciate any suggestions

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.html) to periodically run your `AsyncTask` and get new ping statuses.

For example, if you want to run your `AsyncTask` to check the ping every 5 minutes:

```
ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor scheduler = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(1);
scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(yourAsyncTask, 0, 5, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.. Where should I place this piece in my code?

Comment: That's really dependent on when you want to start and stop getting the ping status. In general, you'll probably want to start it when your app is in the foreground and stop when app is backgrounded, so it doesn't run forever and ever. 

See Activity Lifecycles:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle